# Why I can't auto play several mp3 files by html5 with Android?

Tags: android, html

Simple test is here:

http://jsfiddle.net/Z8z9Q/

```
  var audio        = new Audio();
  var audioElement = document.createElement('audio');

  function __log(e, data) {
    log.innerHTML += "\n" + e + " " + (data || '');
  }

  function play(text) {

      __log("TTS: "+text);
      audio.setAttribute("src", "http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=en&q="+encodeURIComponent(text));
      audio.load();
      audio.play();
      __log("  -- Played");


  }


  setTimeout(function(){play('Hello World')},1000);
  setTimeout(function(){play('Hello World')},3000);
  setTimeout(function(){play('Hello World')},5000);
  setTimeout(function(){play('Hello World')},7000);
  setTimeout(function(){play('Hello World')},9000);
```

This is working fine with my chrome, but I can't play several mp3 files with Android. But same code works fine with one file:

http://jsfiddle.net/D3gaC/2/

```
  var audio = new Audio();
  var audioElement = document.createElement('audio');

  function __log(e, data) {
    log.innerHTML += "\n" + e + " " + (data || '');
  }

  $(document).ready(function() {

    $('#subb').click(function (e) {
      //if (e.which == 13) {
        __log("TTS: "+$('#audiofield').val());
        audio.setAttribute("src", "http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=en&q="+encodeURIComponent($('#audiofield').val()));
        audio.load();
        audio.play();
        __log("  -- Played");
        $('#audiofield').val("");

        //audioElement.setAttribute('src', "http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=en&q="+encodeURIComponent($('#audiofield').val()));
        //audioElement.load()
        //audioElement.play(); 
        //__log("  -- Played method 2");
      //}
    });

  });
```

Where is the problem?

Comment: both those links resulting in 'untrusted connections' (or server errors) won't help.. could you possibly add a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) example?

Comment: @Wilf Thanks for reply. I fixed the problem description.

Comment: Do you have to create the audio element with javascript/jquery? it would be much easier to modify an existing element.

Answer (score 0):

Having the same issue... I think on mobile browsers, audio/video playback cannot occur if not started by user input - setTimeout probably doesn't qualify as user input.